# Finding the first value of at least a certain value

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I spent a few hours on this, so any help would be amazing!

I have a pandas dataframe df. Then I group by one of the columns (A), focus on another column (B) and get the mean of each group:

```
group_mean = df.groupby('A').B.agg('mean')
group = df.groupby('A').B
```

In the same order above, these are the types python reports:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy'>
```

Now the question, how can I, for each group in "group" identify the index of the first element that is equal or greater than the mean. So in other words, if a group has elements 5, 3, 7, 9, 1, 10 and the mean is 8, I want to return the value 3 (to point to "9").

The result can be another groupby object with one number per group (the index).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` to check per group the values greater than the mean, and `idxmax` to get the first True value:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x.ge(x.mean()).idxmax())
```